nodejs cambiar base de datos no funciona en servidor per si en localhost
tengo un problema con nodejs, tengo una app que tiene una base de datos MySQL y uso sequelize para conectar a una tabla de usuarios con un campo llamado BD, ese usuario al hacer login se conecta a la base de datos que hay en ese campo, por ejemplo.

usuario            BD
admin@admin.com   DataBase1
usuario@usuario   DataBase2

el usuario admin@admin.com se conectará a la base de datos DataBase1 para toda la gestión de datos.
El problema que tengo es que si hago un Npm start app.js desde el pc donde desarrollo la aplicación funciona todo bien, cambia la base de datos y puedo trabajar con distintos usuarios y distintas bases de datos.
Ahora, cuando la aplicación la levanto en un servidor online y accedo desde un dominio, la primera vez se conecta a una base de datos y al cambiar de usuario siempre se conecta a la primera base de datos.
Cuando paro la app y vuelvo a ejecutar npm start, entonces vuelvo a repetir el ciclo, se conecta bien con el primer usuario y después no cambia de base de datos hasta que vuelvo a parar i encender la app.
Al principio pensaba que era cosa de PM2 que es lo que uso para gestionar la app, pero me pasa directamente con npm y no se por donde cogerlo.

La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil reproducir tu problema, identificar el error y responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.
